# Angular2 how to open route in new tab

Tags: angular, routes

How can you open a route in Angular2 to a new tab? I know how to use the window.location object. But route params can get complicated with angular and if it's possible using angular APIs then i would rather do it that way.

Comment: Or is there a way to get a routes url with the params?Like a route builder

Comment: Via code or template?